# I want to comapre two different dataframes in different order and also ignoring special characters,spaces. If same then replace it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the one Dataframe A with column A

```
| A |
:---:
|abc|
|xyz|
|bnm|
```

This is the another Dataframe B with column B

```
| B  |
:----:
|ABc |
|ghj |
|X_yz|
|B+NM|
```

Desired Output of the Dataframe B should be and non Dataframe

```
| B |  
:---:
|abc|
|xyz|
|bnm|

| non |
:-----:
| ghj |


regex = r"[a-zA-Z]"
if sorted(re.split(regex, A["A"], re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)) == sorted(re.split(regex, B["B"], re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)):
  B["B"] = B["B"].replace(A["A"])
else:
  non.append(B["B"])
```

I couldnt get the it is error .Please help me with this code

Answer (score 1):

Common string cleansing in `pandas` can be achieved via the [str accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str). You can chain the cleansing steps at once, and then (1) perform inner joins or (2) use `.isin()` to select the wanted rows. Both usages are shown for demonstration purpose, with `.isin()` being the more concise syntax.

## Data

```
import pandas as pd
import io

A = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
A
abc
xyz
bnm
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine='python')

B = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
B
ABc
ghj
X_yz
B+NM
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine='python')
```

## Solution

```
B["B"] = B["B"].str.replace(r"[^A-Za-z]", "", regex=True)\
               .str.lower()\
               .str.strip()  # if there is trailing spaces

# method 1: join
B_matched = B.merge(A, how="inner", left_on="B", right_on="A")[["B"]]
# method 2: isin
B_non = B[~B["B"].isin(B_matched["B"])].rename(columns={"B": "non"})
```

## Output

```
print(B_matched)
     B
0  abc
1  xyz
2  bnm

print(B_non)
   non
1  ghj
```